# ColdFusion soap client

Tags: web-services, coldfusion, wsdl

The following is a sample SOAP 1.2 request and response. The placeholders shown need to be replaced with actual values.

```
POST /CommunicationOfficeService1_0/CompanyAccountXmlService.asmx HTTP/1.1
Host: webservices.nbs.rs
Content-Type: application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: length

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap12:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap12="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
  <soap12:Header>
    <AuthenticationHeader xmlns="http://communicationoffice.nbs.rs">
      <UserName>string</UserName>
      <Password>string</Password>
      <LicenceID>guid</LicenceID>
    </AuthenticationHeader>
  </soap12:Header>
  <soap12:Body>
    <GetCompanyAccountByNationalIdentificationNumber xmlns="http://communicationoffice.nbs.rs">
      <nationalIdentificationNumber>long</nationalIdentificationNumber>
    </GetCompanyAccountByNationalIdentificationNumber>
  </soap12:Body>
</soap12:Envelope>

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: length

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap12:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap12="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
  <soap12:Body>
    <GetCompanyAccountByNationalIdentificationNumberResponse xmlns="http://communicationoffice.nbs.rs">
      <GetCompanyAccountByNationalIdentificationNumberResult>string</GetCompanyAccountByNationalIdentificationNumberResult>
    </GetCompanyAccountByNationalIdentificationNumberResponse>
  </soap12:Body>
</soap12:Envelope>
```

I have generated the ColdFusion code that looks like this

```
<cfsavecontent variable="soapBody">
<cfoutput>

POST /CommunicationOfficeService1_0/CompanyAccountXmlService.asmx HTTP/1.1
Host: webservices.nbs.rs
Content-Type: application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: length

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap12:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap12="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
  <soap12:Header>
    <AuthenticationHeader xmlns="http://communicationoffice.nbs.rs">
      <UserName>my_username</UserName>
      <Password>my_password</Password>
      <LicenceID>My_licence_id</LicenceID>
    </AuthenticationHeader>
  </soap12:Header>
  <soap12:Body>
    <GetCompanyAccountByNationalIdentificationNumber xmlns="http://communicationoffice.nbs.rs">
      <nationalIdentificationNumber>20774550</nationalIdentificationNumber>
    </GetCompanyAccountByNationalIdentificationNumber>
  </soap12:Body>
</soap12:Envelope>
</cfoutput>
</cfsavecontent>



<!---
Now that we have our SOAP body defined, we need to post it as
a SOAP request to the Campaign Monitor website. Notice that
when I POST the SOAP request, I am NOT required to append the
"WSDL" flag to the target URL (this is only required when you
actually want to get the web service definition).
--->
<cfhttp
url="https://webservices.nbs.rs/CommunicationOfficeService1_0/CompanyAccountXmlService.asmx"
method="post"
result="httpResponse">

<!---
Most SOAP action require some sort of SOAP Action header
to be used.
--->
<cfhttpparam
type="header"
name="SOAPAction"
value="http://communicationoffice.nbs.rs/GetCompanyAccountByNationalIdentificationNumber"
/>

<!---
I typically use this header because CHTTP cannot handle
GZIP encoding. This "no-compression" directive tells the
server not to pass back GZIPed content.
--->
<cfhttpparam
type="header"
name="accept-encoding"
value="no-compression"

/>

<!---
When posting the SOAP body, I use the CFHTTPParam type of
XML. This does two things: it posts the XML as a the BODY
and sets the mime-type to be XML.

NOTE: Be sure to Trim() your XML since XML data cannot be
parsed with leading whitespace.
--->
<cfhttpparam
type="xml"
value="#trim( soapBody )#"
/>

</cfhttp>


<!---
When the HTTP response comes back, our SOAP response will be
in the FileContent atribute. SOAP always returns valid XML,
even if there was an error (assuming the error was NOT in the
communication, but rather in the data).
--->
<cfif find( "200", httpResponse.statusCode )>

<!--- Parse the XML SOAP response. --->
<cfset soapResponse = xmlParse( httpResponse.fileContent ) />

<!---
Query for the response nodes using XPath. Because the
SOAP XML document has name spaces, querying the document
becomes a little funky. Rather than accessing the node
name directly, we have to use its local-name().
--->
<cfset responseNodes = xmlSearch(
soapResponse,
"//*[ local-name() = 'Subscriber.AddAndResubscribeResult' ]"
) />

<!---
Once we have the response node, we can use our typical
ColdFusion struct-style XML node access.
--->
<cfoutput>

Code: #responseNodes[ 1 ].Code.xmlText#
<br />
Success: #responseNodes[ 1 ].Message.xmlText#

</cfoutput>

</cfif>
```

I have none results . The web service uses this is the web site

This is the wsdl file

[Serbian National Bank Web Service](https://webservices.nbs.rs/CommunicationOfficeService1_0/CompanyAccountXmlService.asmx?WSDL)

How to make this web service run

Comment: you're getting no results or an error? If you're not getting an error you're probably connecting successfully.

Comment: I am getting no results , what is strange is that this web service is easy to use from c sharp and php but java - fails to generate all the right classes by using netbeans wizard and cold fusion gives me nothing back . The web site and web service is made in asp tech.Maybe I am missing something ...

Comment: if you're getting no results then you've sent wrong criteria. If it couldn't connect you should be getting a separate error.

Comment: All the parameters are ok - user name , password and licenceID it may be that in the code of cfhttpparam that I do something wrong!?

Answer (score 0):

I've modified a function I've used in the past to pass data form ColdFusion to Dynamics GP via soap.

```
<cffunction name="callWebService" access="public" output="false">
    <cfargument name="soap" type="xml" required="true">
    <cfhttp url="https://webservices.nbs.rs/CommunicationOfficeService1_0/CompanyAccountXmlService.asmx"  method="post">
        <cfhttpparam type="header" name="content-type" value="application/soap+xml">
        <cfhttpparam type="header" name="SOAPAction" value="http://communicationoffice.nbs.rs/GetCompanyAccountByNationalIdentificationNumber">
        <cfhttpparam type="header" name="accept-encoding" value="no-compression">
        <cfhttpparam type="header" name="content-length" value="#len(Arguments.soap)#">
        <cfhttpparam type="header" name="charset" value="utf-8">
        <cfhttpparam type="xml" name="message" value="#trim(Arguments.soap)#">
    </cfhttp>
    <cfreturn Trim(cfhttp.FileContent)>
</cffunction>
```

I believe I've updated the `<cfhttpparam />s` necessary for the web service you've linked. I would recommend using a software called SOAP UI to test your connection to the service and SOAP XML body outside of ColdFusion. In my above function, the argument soap would be  your saved content "soapBody".

One thing needs to be fixed in your soapBody. The text prior to the start of XML is information regarding data that needs to be in the HTTP header, and I've only seen these values imputed as `<cfhttpparam />`.

The reason I think you may not be getting the desired 200 response with your above code is that the XML body is incorrectly formatted with the WSDL HTTP header example text. I also did not see the length of the body being declared as well.

While trying to set up your connection try just dumping `httpResponse` out until you start seeing valid soap responses from the server.